# How can I query JSON data with a nested, nested array using JSON_TABLE in SQL?

Tags: arrays, json

enter code hereI am kind of new to JSON and trying to query a complex JSON data structure using JSON_TABLE. Here is the data and a the query I came up with. The issue is that phonenumber is an array with in an array and not displaying the results. Any help would be appreciated.

---

### Sample JSON Data

{
"instId": 1,
"instappId": 1000,
"instappNumber": "Z1009",
"appDate": "2020-09-19T09:29:04.633",
"contactInfo": {
"instId": 1,
"instappId":1000,
"firstName": "Dan",
"middleName": null,
"lastName": "Wood",
"emailAddress": "dan.wood@email.com",
"phoneNumbers": [
{
"instId": 1,
"phoneID: 2001,
"phoneType": "Home Phone",
"phoneNumber": "1234567890",
}
}
]
"workHistory": [
{
"instId": 1,
"companyiterationID: 1,
"companyName": "ABC Inc,
"startDate": "2019-01-11,
"EndDate": null,

```
            }
        ]
```

}

---

### Query

SELECT A.*
FROM
mytable b,
JSON_TABLE
(b.json_data, '$.data[*]'
COLUMNS
(
instId NUMBER(5) PATH '$.instId',
instappId number(15) PATH '$.instappId',
instappNumber VARCHAR2(30) PATH '$.instappNumber',
appDate DATE PATH '$.appDate',
NESTED PATH  '$.contactInfo[*]' COLUMNS (
firstName VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$.firstName',
middleName VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$.middleName',
lastName VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$.lastName',
emailAddress VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$.emailAddress',
NESTED PATH  '$.phoneNumbers[*]' COLUMNS (
phoneNumberId NUMBER(15) PATH '$.phoneNumberId',
phoneType VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$.phoneType',
phoneNumber VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$.phoneNumber')),
NESTED PATH  '$.workHistory[*]' COLUMNS (
companyName VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$.companyName',
startDate DATE PATH '$.startDate'
endDate DATE PATH '$.endDate')
)
)
A;

Comment: Can you verify if your JSON is valid? - I think it's not. Also, this is Oracle, right? if so, please [edit] and add the appropiated tags

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and definitely, your JSON is not valid.

- Check closely your JSON - check first how you're bulding this object or how you're receiving it - because it's not valid.

This is the code I was able to build:

```
SELECT *
FROM JSON_TABLE('{
    "instId": 1,
    "instappId": 1000,
    "instappNumber": "Z1009",
    "appDate": "2020-09-19T09:29:04.633",
    "contactInfo": {
        "instId": 1,
        "instappId": 1000,
        "firstName": "Dan",
        "middleName": null,
        "lastName": "Wood",
        "emailAddress": "dan.wood@email.com",
        "phoneNumbers": [{
                "instId": 1,
                "phoneID": 2001,
                "phoneType": "Home Phone",
                "phoneNumber": "1234567890"
            }]
        },
    "workHistory": [{
        "instId": 1,
        "companyiterationID": 1,
        "companyName": "ABC Inc",
        "startDate": "2019-01-11",
        "EndDate": null
      }]
}', '$[*]' COLUMNS(instId NUMBER(5) PATH '$.instId',
           instappId number(15) PATH '$.instappId',
           instappNumber VARCHAR2(30) PATH '$.instappNumber',
           appDate DATE PATH '$.appDate',
           firstName VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.contactInfo.firstName', 
           middleName VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$.middleName',
           lastName VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$.lastName',
           emailAddress VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$.emailAddress',
  NESTED PATH  '$.phoneNumbers[*]' COLUMNS (
             phoneNumberId NUMBER(15) PATH '$.phoneNumberId',
             phoneType VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$.phoneType',
             phoneNumber VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$.phoneNumber'),
  NESTED PATH  '$.workHistory[*]' COLUMNS (
            companyName VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$.companyName',
            startDate DATE PATH '$.startDate',
            endDate DATE PATH '$.EndDate'))
  );
```

| INSTID | INSTAPPID | INSTAPPNUMBER | APPDATE | FIRSTNAME | MIDDLENAME | LASTNAME | EMAILADDRESS | PHONENUMBERID | PHONETYPE | PHONENUMBER | COMPANYNAME | STARTDATE | ENDDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | Z1009 | 19-SEP-20 | Dan | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | ABC Inc | 11-JAN-19 | *null* |

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/b-NVoFxQ)

Comment: Thanks for your time and response. I will check the JSON structure as it is from a legitimate API which we are using to download the file. I am quite sure that there won't be any issue with the structure as it is used by many applications.